# Remove class on click anywhere, unless a certain textbox is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to improve the following script a little:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $('.home.active').click();
    $('.home').removeClass("active");
});
```

This works, but it works when I don't want it to work.  For example, I have a textbox.  If that textbox gets focus, the class should not be removed, but if anything else on the page is clicked, the class should be removed.  So I tried the following, which does not work:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if( $('#txtHomeSearch').focus() ) {
        // don't remove class
    } else {
        $('.home.active').click();
        $('.home').removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

This stops the class being remove altogether, no matter where I click, and the textbox always has focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to determine the `id` of the clicked element:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "txtHomeSearch") {
        // Don't remove class.
    } else {
        $('.home.active').click();
        $('.home').removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if( event.target.id == 'txtHomeSearch' )
        return;

    $('.home.active').click();
    $('.home').removeClass("active");

});
```

Whatever the `$('.home.active').click();` does, might screw it up.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the source of the event using the `target` property.

```
if ($(event.target).prop('id') == 'txtHomeSearch') {
   //don't remove class
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try. You might need to drop the `#` from `#txtHomeSearch` I can't remember off the top of my head.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if( $(this).attr('id') == '#txtHomeSearch') {
        // don't remove class
    } else {
        $('.home.active').click();
        $('.home').removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event.target property to cross-check the element.
The problem is your `if( $('#txtHomeSearch').focus() )` ... that's not checking if it's in focus, its GIVING it focus.

to select a focused element you can use the jquery(1.6) `:focus` selector, use `$(document.activeElement)` for future reference